# Hilbert space and orthogonal projection $P_M(u)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M$ a closed subspace of an Hilbert space $H$. I want to prove $\forall u \in H,  P_M(u)$ is the unique element so that $\|u-P_M(u)\|=\min_{v \in M} \|u-v\|$

Let $P_M(w)$ another element that realizes the minimal distance ($\|w-P_M(w)\|=\min_{v \in M} \|w-v\|$ but how can I prove unicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u\in H$, $P_M(u)\in M$ be the orthogonal projection on M and $w\in M$. Then, $u-P_M(u)\perp (P_M(u)-w)$, thus

$\|u-w\|^2=\|(u-P_m(u)) + (P_M(u)-w)\|^2=\|u-P_m(u)\|^2 + \|P_M(u)-w)\|^2\geq \|u-P_m(u)\|^2$

by Pythagorean's theorem. Hence, $\min_{w\in M}\|u-w\|=\|u-P_M(u)\|$.